# Jquery toggle divs & rotate with fades

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, toggle

Ok i've came across a feature on a website and to me it looks amazing, i've been trying to recreate a similar feature but can't even get close.

You can see the feature here - http://mitchell-me.com/ 
If you click Services. There is the Electrical & Mechanical.

When you click the buttons, the circle rotates, the icon on it fades into the new icon & the div's fade out/in. I've been trying to do this using jquery toggles but i just can't get close.

I'm hoping to get any/all advice or simple code samples here. Thanks in advance i've been losing my mind for 3days with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to rebuild this effect in jsFiddle and this is the [result](http://jsfiddle.net/ldaniell14260/4FMGG/). If you use this code, make sure you include this: `<script src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/files/jQueryRotate.2.2.js"></script>` otherwise the rotation will not work. All the rotation and fading is done via jQuery to get a better compatibility.

Comment: Spot on thankyou I can modify it to fit a little better etc but thankyou for this :)

Answer (score 1):

Their javascript seems to be changing the CSS. The CSS does the transformation and fading work.

I [snooped through their javascript](http://mitchell-me.com/QuickOptimizer/Cache/43b42ff4cc2c854d0f53e3a3eef13bd85f3aff56b295be5a866e5835449041e2.js)...

```
$("#service li").click(function(e){e.preventDefault();var index=$(this).index();$('#service li').removeClass("active");if(!$(this).hasClass("active")&&!intrans){intrans=true;switch(index){case 0:TweenLite.to($(".dial"),1.5,{css:{shortRotation:0},ease:Expo.easeInOut});TweenLite.to($(".gear"),1.5,{css:{autoAlpha:0,rotation:0},ease:Expo.easeInOut});TweenLite.to($(".bulb"),1.5,{css:{autoAlpha:1,rotation:0},ease:Expo.easeInOut});$('#electric, #electric1').delay(800).animate({opacity:1},{easing:easeType,duration:"100",complete:function(){}});$('#mechanic, #mechanic1').delay(200).animate({opacity:0},{easing:easeType,duration:"100",complete:function(){intrans=false}});break;case 1:TweenLite.to($(".dial"),1.5,{css:{shortRotation:115,transformOrigin:"103px 103px"},ease:Expo.easeInOut});TweenLite.to($(".bulb"),1.5,{css:{autoAlpha:0,x:0,y:0,rotation:120,transformOrigin:"20px 40px"},ease:Expo.easeInOut});TweenLite.to($(".gear"),1.5,{css:{autoAlpha:1,x:0,y:0,rotation:120,transformOrigin:"50px 48px"},ease:Expo.easeInOut});$('#electric, #electric1').delay(200).animate({opacity:0},{easing:easeType,duration:"100",complete:function(){}});$('#mechanic, #mechanic1').delay(800).animate({opacity:1},{easing:easeType,duration:"100",complete:function(){intrans=false}});break;}}
```

And it looks like they're using [Tweenlite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) and [Tweenmax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/) for it.

Comment: Hi thanks for that  its making a bit more sense. So basically the above, handles it all, so it should be a matter of creating the html elements, calling the tweenlite source & that function. Then just the two links (directed to #) are controlling the function call. 

Did what i just wrote make any sense lol